# object exists in AWS S3 bucket in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to check an object before creating a signed url. I need to use custom Expires. I am using following code.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'YOURKEY', secretAccessKey:'YOURSECRET'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3()
params = {Bucket:'BUCKET_NAME', Key: 'TEST.pdf', Expires: 10000} 

s3.headObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err,err.code); // an error occurred
    else     
    {   
      s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('error: ' + err); 
      } else {
           console.log('Signed URL: ' + url);
      }
      });  
    }           // successful response
});
```

I am getting following error in headObject. I know headObject doesn't support Expiries.

```
 { [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Expires' found in params]
  message: 'Unexpected key \'Expires\' found in params',
  code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
  time: Wed Apr 06 2016 10:14:53 GMT-0500 (CDT) }
```

How can i use params with custom expires in both headObject and getSignedUrl ?

Comment: Create one params object for the `headObject` call and another params object for the `getSignedUrl` call. Why do you think you need to use the same object in both calls?

Comment: i could do that. If i don't mentioned expires it's default is 900s. i posted this question to find any way to use custom expires.

Comment: I don't think you understand. HeadObject doesn't take an expires parameter, which is exactly what your error message is saying, so you can't pass an expires parameter to that method call. It doesn't make sense to pass it in that method call because you aren't SETTING anything on the object, you are simply getting some object data. There is nothing to set an expires setting on in that method call. You should only pass the expires header in the getSignedUrl method call because that is when you are creating a URL that needs to expire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the exact code to fix your issue. This should really be self evident if you just read the error message you are getting.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'YOURKEY', secretAccessKey:'YOURSECRET'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3()
headParams = {Bucket:'BUCKET_NAME', Key: 'TEST.pdf'} 
urlParams = {Bucket:'BUCKET_NAME', Key: 'TEST.pdf', Expires: 10000} 

s3.headObject(headParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err,err.code); // an error occurred
    else     
    {   
      s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', urlParams, function (err, url) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('error: ' + err); 
      } else {
           console.log('Signed URL: ' + url);
      }
      });  
    }           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Well then I guess your question "How can i use params with custom expires in both headObject and getSignedUrl?" is that you can't. It doesn't make sense to do that, so don't try.

Comment: How do you return the value of the Signed URL rather than doing console.log?

Comment: @user923227 res.status(200).send(url) in place of console.log

Answer (score 1):

Using V3 client

```
import {S3Client, HeadObjectCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const client = new S3Client(config);
const input = {
    Bucket: "STRING_VALUE", // required
    Key: "STRING_VALUE", // required
};
try {
    const command = new HeadObjectCommand(input);
    const response = await client.send(command);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Object does not exist")
}
```

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/headobjectcommand.html